# Как сделать конструкцию "SELECT IF THEN UPDATE"

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть таблица bank, в ней 3 столбца:
id, owner, money
Мне нужно "перекинуть" X количество money из N строки в строку M, я сделал запрос, но проблема в том, что из строки N вычитает money, но когда добавляет в строку M, то там надо как-то сделать проверку, есть ли в N строке money >= X, вот мой запрос:

```
UPDATE bank SET money = CASE id 
    WHEN '2' THEN IF(owner = '15', money+'5', money) 
    WHEN '1' THEN IF(owner = '15' AND money >= '5', money-'5', money)
    END WHERE id IN ('1', '2')
```

Здесь из строки с ID 1 вычитает 5 из поля money при условии, что эти 5 были в money и прибавляет к строке ID 2 в поле money 5, но надо сделать туда условие чтобы проверяло, есть ли в строке с ID 1 поле money >= 5

Comment: WHERE id IN ('1', '2') and exists(select 1 from bank where id = 1 and money >= 5)

Comment: #1093 - Не допускается указание таблицы 'bank' в списке таблиц FROM для внесения в нее изменений

Comment: видимо у mysql с этим какие-то проблемы. на английском ресурсе есть похожий вопрос. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45494/mysql-error-1093-cant-specify-target-table-for-update-in-from-clause

Comment: вообще придется переделать в update с join. только я не совсем понял при каких условиях что менять. т.е. если в строке с id=1 money оказался < 5, то не надо ничего не менять в обоих строках, а когда >=5 то менять так же сразу в обоих строках. И таким образом ни при каких условиях не должна меняться только одна строка ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну типа

```
SET @x = 5; -- сумма
SET @m = 2; -- получатель
SET @n = 1; -- плательщик

UPDATE bank, (SELECT 1 enough FROM bank WHERE id = @n AND money >= @x) dummy
SET money = money + @x * CASE id WHEN @m THEN 1 ELSE -1 END
WHERE id IN (@m, @n)
  AND dummy.enough;
```

Comment: Хотя наверное `AND dummy.enough` - лишнее...